# How to add assumptions in limit in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to add some assumptions in limit.
Suppose `0<x<1`, then $$limit_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$$

```
from sympy import *
x = var('x, n')
limit(x**n, n, oo)
```

But I get an error `NotImplementedError: Result depends on the sign of sign(log(x))`.

Is there some way in sympy to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments the solution below fails with the same `NotImplementedError` as in the question (as of November 2019) saying that the answer depends on sign(log(x)). It seems that this sign problem can not be solved with `assuming` but only with the `positive` parameter of `Symbol`. So one way around the issue is to describe 0 < x < 1 as exp(-y) for y > 0:

```
from sympy import *

y = Symbol("y", positive=True)
n = Symbol("n")

print(limit(exp(-y)**n, n, oo)) # outputs 0
```

---

To assume something you can say:

```
from sympy.assumptions import assuming, Q
with assuming(...):
```

see here: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/assume.html

In your case:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.assumptions import assuming, Q

x, n = symbols("x n")
with assuming(Q.is_true(0 < x), Q.is_true(x <1)):
    print(limit(x**n, n, oo))
```

Comment: This example doesn't work. First, you didn't provide a working code, the bracket is missing, but this is a minor issue. Next, limit should be with n going to infinity, not x. Finally, after correcting all the mistakes one obtains `NotImplementedError`. It seems that, unfortunately, the feature is indeed still not implemented, as for September 2017.