# Sympy - limit() Error: Result depends on the sign

Tags: python, sympy, calculus

I'm attempting to solve the following problem:

[image]

Applying the following I get the correct answer.

```
α, t, x = symbols('α t x')
integrate(α*x*exp(-α*x), (x, 0, oo), conds='none')
```

To check the solution (`1/α`) I attempted the following.

```
limit(integrate(α*x*exp(-α*x), (x, 0, t), conds='none'), t, oo)
```

But this yields `NotImplementedError: Result depends on the sign of -sign(α)` as well as a further `**NotImplementedError**` with no description. The function works for real numbers but not `oo`. How can I work around this problem?

Comment: This seems to be a bug, because `limit(1/α, t, oo)` doesn't raise this error.

Comment: Also, storing the result of `limit(integrate(α*x*exp(-α*x), (x, 0, t), conds='none'), t, oo)` in variable `result` and then calling `limit(result, t, oo)` does not raise this error.

Comment: Actually, the Exception is correct.
The error lies in giving the answer `1/α`. You can easily convince yourself by setting `α = -1`. Then the integral is `-oo`.
It is supposed to work by assumption, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587985/how-to-add-assumptions-in-limit-in-sympy, but it seems to be not implemented, yet.

Comment: Couldn't manage to get  `with assuming(...)` working, but posted a solution that seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the argument `positive = True` to the `symbols` function mitigates this issue.

```
α, t, x = symbols('α t x', positive = True)

func = integrate(α*x*exp(-α*x), (x, 0, t), conds='none')

(limit(func, t, oo))
```

Yielding `1/α`